# How to automatically commit all changed files in directory at certain time?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, tortoisegit

I am taking my first foray into Version control with Git, and I've downloaded TortoiseGit to make the process easier (might not be important to the question, but because I use it I don't really know any command line commands).

I am trying to set up a system where all changed but uncommitted files will automatically commit once a week. I want it to act just like a regular commit, with a dedicated author (something to indicate it was an automatic commit) and a custom message. I don't think this sounds too complicated, but I have absolutely no experience with Git and I can't find any solution on the internet, at least not after about half an hour of searching.

Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible, and if so, what's the best way to go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Windows or Linux? You would probably need to setup a cron job.

Comment: Windows. Sorry, should have included that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to do a cron task (https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/) or a task scheduler under windows, with the following git command:

```
  git add -u <<< only add tracked files
  git commit -m "your commit message" <<< commit all 
  your added files
  git push origin YourBranch
```

This should work 
Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Task scheduler seems like a good idea, but I need to be able to push this feature out to multiple systems. Do you know if it's possible to write a PowerShell script to schedule a task to run another script that would make the commit?

Comment: You can add as many command in your cron as you need. But if all your systems are connected to the same fork, then push it once an git pull on each server you need. Then you will be up to date everywhere :)

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)